# what ..x.. stands for in ggplot notation

Tags: r, ggplot2

Often I see notation like that in ggplot or ggridges:

Consider a generic `df`:

```
ggplot(df, aes ( x = x , y = factor(y) , fill = ..x.. ) )
```

What `..x..` represents in the code above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When building a plot, ggplot2 creates a data.frame with all data it needs for plotting. This notation can be used to access columns of that data.frame. You don't provide a full example, so I'm showing it with `stat_summary`:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg, color = ..ymin..)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", size = 2)
print(p)
```

[image: resulting plot]

```
g <- ggplot_build(p)
g$data
#[[1]]
#   colour x group        y     ymin     ymax PANEL size linetype shape fill alpha stroke
#1 #56B1F7 4    -1 26.66364 24.23614 29.19114     1    2        1    19   NA    NA      1
#2 #316794 6    -1 19.74286 18.77107 20.74321     1    2        1    19   NA    NA      1
#3 #132B43 8    -1 15.10000 13.75696 16.30714     1    2        1    19   NA    NA      1
```

As you see, `stat_summary` calculates `ymin` values and we can map `color` to this (internal) variable.

Comment: Would like to add that you could also use `stat(ymin)` instead of `..ymin..`. I think the `stat(x)` notation is preferred (by the people at ggplot) because it is less confusing than the `..x..` and communicates more clearly what variable is mapped to an aesthetic (namely a calculated statistic).